# Context free grammar for non-palindrome

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I need a CFG which will generate strings other than palindromes. The solution has been provided and is as below.(Introduction to theory of computation - Sipser)

```
R -> XRX | S
S -> aTb | bTa
T -> XTX | X | <epsilon>
X -> a | b
```

I get the general idea of how this grammar works. It mandates the insertion of a sub-string which has corresponding non-equal alphabets on its either half, through the production `S -> aTb | bTa`, thus ensuring that a palindrome could never be generated.

I will write down the semantics of the first two productions as I have understood it,

- `S` generates strings which cannot be palindromes because their 1st and last alphabets are not equal
- `R` consists of at-least one `S` as a sub-string ensuring that it is never a palindrome.

I don't completely understand the semantics of the third production, i.e. .

```
   T -> XTX | X | <epsilon>
   X -> a | b
```

The way I see it, T can generate any combination of a and b, i.e. {a, b}*. Why could it not have been like

```
T -> XT | <epsilon>
X -> a | b
```

Aren't the two equivalent? As the later is more intuitive, why isn't it used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction the book I believe is shows some symmetry for better reading.

It means it first construct anything, T. Then there is a wrapper S, so that it becomes no longer a palindrome S, and then build everything upon it.

The latter might seems to intuitive. However, if you think of the definition or construction of palindrome, you might understand why writing in such way make sense.

If you have a palindrome, you would construct something like this

> T -> aTa | bTb | a | b | epsilon

And if we want to violate construction, we just need to make sure that there is one layer looks like this (I use T to be one layer and S to something one step after T)

> S -> aTb

And other layer we generally do not care

> S -> aTa | aTb | bTa | bTb

So that forms the inner layer (T) and outer layer(R) and the layer that violates the construction of palindrome(S). Even thought T seems to be redundant, but it forms the similar construction like R, thus expressing the intention of the construction.

Comment: you're wrong in the last paragraph. should be aSa and bSb

Answer (score 9):

The best way to ensure that you have a grammar that generates only non-palindromes is the following:
Define:

- Pal - The language of palindromes
- {a, b}* - The language containing all strings over the alphabet {a,
  b}
- Non-Pal - The language of all strings that are not palindromes (i.e.
  not in Pal)

Observer that non-Pal = {a, b}* - Pal

The grammar for Pal is know to be the following:

- S -> lambda | a | b | aSa | bSb

The grammar for {a, b}* can be written as follows:

- S -> lambda | Sa | Sb

Now to construct the grammar of non-Pal observe the following:

- If x is an element of non-Pal then:

  - axa is an element of non-Pal
  - bxb is an element of non-Pal
- If y is an element of {a, b}* then:

  - ayb is an element of non-Pal
  - bya is an element of non-Pal

Combining all this information the grammar for non-Pal would be:

- S -> aSa | bSb | aAb | bAa
- A -> lambda | Aa | Ab

I hope this clarifies things

Answer (score 5):

The definition of `T` in that grammer does indeed appear to be unnecessary complication. `T` can generate any string of `a`s and `b`s, so the simpler definition would have been just as good.

I can only guess that the productions are given as they are because of the sausage-factory nature of writing a book.

**ORIGINAL WRONG ANSWER:**

They are not equivalent, because `X` itself cannot be `<epsilon>`, and `T` is not any combination of `a` and `b`. `T` can only expand to a palindrome (including the empty palindrome, a single character, or a palindrome with an unpaired central character).

If `X` could be empty, then `T` could expand to anything, but it can't.

*NOTE*

This answer is based on the supposition that the author’s intention for the production `T -> XTX` is that the two identical non-terminals in the substitution must represent identical strings of characters. Since I don't have the text to look at, I don't know if this assumption is well-founded except that it is motivated by the question itself. This supposition could be a mistake by the author if that is not the case elsewhere. I think that, in general, this requirement is not true of context-free grammers.

The correct productions would be:

```
R -> aRa | bRb | S
S -> aTb | bTa
T -> aTa | bTb | a | b | <epsilon>
```

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that, yes, you're right, this grammer is messed up. I couldn't find anything about it on the errata page for that book, so you might want to tell the author about it.

Comment: My mistake. I did not mean to show that X could become <epsilon>. X remains unchanged. It can become only 'a' or 'b'. I have corrected the question now. Further I don't understand how T can expand only to become a Palindrome as you say. Consider aabb, a non-palindrome. It can be generated as T->XTX->XXTXX->aa<epsilon>bb = aabb. Use of same variables does not mean that they be substituted the same non-terminal.

Comment: I don't think that the productions are wrong. I can see that they generate only non-palindromes. I only don't understand, in my view, the twisted way the T production is presented and am wondering if there is a rationale behind it

Comment: @Abhijith Madhav - Yes, it does look like unnecessary complication. For a few minutes I was taken in by the core-palindrome theory, but that appears to be incorrect. The non-palindromeness of the result doesn't depend on T at all. It can be anything. The complicated definition appears to be an historical artifact of the grammer production process.

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge how can you produce aaaaabab using your CFG?

Comment: @FilipIonDorinel - The productions cannot produce that string. I do not think the intent is to produce *all* non-palindromes of a's and b's. Rather it is to produce a particular language that consists of only non-palindromes. I suspect that if one wanted to take the time, it may be possible to prove that no CFG exists that can produce all non-palindromes of a particular alphabet without producing any palindromes. But I'm by no means certain of that.

Comment: @FilipIonDorinel - On further review, now I think it is possible like this: 
`S -> ab | ba | aPb | bPa | aSa | bSb | aSb | bSa` and 
`P -> a | b | aa | bb | aPa | bPb | <epsilon>`
Then the string you propose can be generated like this:
`S (S -> aSb) aSb (S -> aSa) aaSab (S -> aPb) aaaPbab (P -> aa) aaaaabab`
In this scheme `S` is always a non-palindrome, and `P` is a palindrome (possible empty) that appears in its center.

Answer (score 2):

I found this definition of a non-palindrome quite intuitive. I assume that the author
started with a definition for a palindrome

```
R -> aRa | bRb | a | b | <epsilon>
```

and now asked, how this definition can be "ruined".

That is, he unfolded the definition three times, exchanged one `aRa | bRb` by `aRb | bRa` and generalized the remaining productions to `(a|b)R(a|b)`.

Comment: The author actually gives this CFG in one of the exercise problems and asks us to write in plain english the language generated by it. Though it looks intuitive now to me I took a loooooong time figuring it out.

Comment: This grammar doesn't generate all non-palindromes. For instance, *aabb* is not a palindrome but is not in the language of the grammar.

Comment: @danportin: Above grammar is the starting point. You need to unfold it several times to obtain the non-palindrome version. It explains why the middle `T` where `(a|b)*` would be good enough contains this complex structure that confused @Abhijith.

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty. If you edit your answer, I can remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Any Non Palindrome can be split along middle ,
such that x(k) != x(k+ n)

n= half length 
x(i) = character at i th position

Keeping that in mind a simple solution would be

```
R  -> aRa | bRb | T
T  -> aSb | bSa
S  -> aRa | bRb | a | b | T | episoln
```

It can generate all non palindromes