# Context free grammar for non-palindromes

Tags: context-free-grammar

So I found a person asking about a context free grammar for non-palindromes here: 
[Context free grammar for non-palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495154/context-free-grammar-for-non-palindrome)

And the given CFGs were:

```
R -> XRX | S
S -> aTb | bTa
T -> XTX | X | <epsilon>
X -> a | b
```

and

```
R -> aRa | bRb | S
S -> aTb | bTa
T -> aTa | bTb | a | b | <epsilon>
```

My question: wouldn't 'aaabba' not be accepted by this CFG despite it not being a palindrome?
Would this CFG be more correct if it had a rule more like:

```
T -> aTa | bTb | aTb | bTa | a | b | <epsilon>
```

instead of the last line given above? Or am I misunderstanding something? :<

Comment: Probably better-suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: which one's the start state? S or R?

Comment: I was guessing R since its on the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one's fine, but the second isn't.

For the first one, the sequence is

```
R -> XRX -> aRa -> aSa -> aaTba -> aaXTXba -> aaaTbba -> aaabba.
```

I believe you are right in saying the second one is incapable of generating all non-palindromes.

Comment: Ohh, so the X's in XTX can be different? >_<

Comment: `X -> a | b` means `X` can be either, and the choice is independent for each `X` encountered. Same way you can use `R -> XRX` one time and `R -> S` the next.